# RabbitMQ Prometheus Metric "/api/metrics" returns "Empty reply from server"

Tags: rabbitmq, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus

Running RMQ on a GKE pod.

> Version: 3.7.14

The prom target shows that the endpoint is down. While checking the endpoint response manually the metrics is returning an "Empty Reply from server"

```
root@rabbitmq-0:/# curl 0.0.0.0:15672/api/metrics
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Plugins seem to be installed correctly for RMQ

```
root@rabbitmq-0:/# rabbitmq-plugins list
Listing plugins with pattern ".*" ...
 Configured: E = explicitly enabled; e = implicitly enabled
 | Status: * = running on rab...@rabbitmq-0.rabbitmq-svc.default.svc.cluster.local
 |/
[E*] prometheus_rabbitmq_exporter      3.7.9.1
[  ] rabbitmq_amqp1_0                  3.7.14
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_backend_cache       3.7.14
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_backend_http        3.7.14
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap        3.7.14
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl       3.7.14
[  ] rabbitmq_consistent_hash_exchange 3.7.14
[  ] rabbitmq_event_exchange           3.7.14
[  ] rabbitmq_federation               3.7.14
[  ] rabbitmq_federation_management    3.7.14
[  ] rabbitmq_jms_topic_exchange       3.7.14
[E*] rabbitmq_management               3.7.14
[e*] rabbitmq_management_agent         3.7.14
[  ] rabbitmq_mqtt                     3.7.14
[  ] rabbitmq_peer_discovery_aws       3.7.14
[e*] rabbitmq_peer_discovery_common    3.7.14
[  ] rabbitmq_peer_discovery_consul    3.7.14
[  ] rabbitmq_peer_discovery_etcd      3.7.14
[E*] rabbitmq_peer_discovery_k8s       3.7.14
[  ] rabbitmq_random_exchange          3.7.14
[  ] rabbitmq_recent_history_exchange  3.7.14
[  ] rabbitmq_sharding                 3.7.14
[  ] rabbitmq_shovel                   3.7.14
[  ] rabbitmq_shovel_management        3.7.14
[  ] rabbitmq_stomp                    3.7.14
[  ] rabbitmq_top                      3.7.14
[  ] rabbitmq_tracing                  3.7.14
[  ] rabbitmq_trust_store              3.7.14
[e*] rabbitmq_web_dispatch             3.7.14
[  ] rabbitmq_web_mqtt                 3.7.14
[  ] rabbitmq_web_mqtt_examples        3.7.14
[  ] rabbitmq_web_stomp                3.7.14
[  ] rabbitmq_web_stomp_examples       3.7.14

root@rabbitmq-0:/# rabbitmqctl eval 'application:get_env(rabbit, plugins_dir).'
{ok,":/usr/lib/rabbitmq/plugins:/opt/rabbitmq/plugins"}

root@rabbitmq-0:/# ls -la /usr/lib/rabbitmq/plugins
total 524
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   4096 Jun  3  2019 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   4096 Jun  3  2019 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  12491 May  8  2019 accept-0.3.5.ez
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 212564 May  8  2019 prometheus-4.3.0.ez
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  13980 May  8  2019 prometheus_cowboy-0.1.7.ez
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  21555 May  8  2019 prometheus_httpd-2.1.10.ez
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  20000 May  8  2019 prometheus_process_collector-1.4.3.ez
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 237330 May  8  2019 prometheus_rabbitmq_exporter-3.7.9.1.ez
```

Can someone suggest what else can be looked at?

Comment: This question (being about configuration of existing third-party app) is off-topic for SO. Consider asking as [su].

Comment: Do you get a response from `curl 0.0.0.0:15672/`?